# Search results going to 404

Tags: search

I am pretty confused about this, since I upgraded Expression Engine to 2.5.5 all the searches from the simple search form are going to the 404 page. Here is the search form

```
    {exp:search:simple_form channel="bike_families|blog|faq|features|support_resources|team_member|bikes" no_result_page="search/noresults" result_page="search/index"}
         <input type="search" name="keywords" placeholder="Search" id="keywords" value="" size="18" maxlength="100">
         <input type="submit" value="Search" class="submit small"
{/exp:search:simple_form}
```

I have checked all my log files and there are no error messages being reported, simplifying the form by removing the channel definition also does not help. I made sure both the result page and the no result page exist and even tried changing the url.

I also dugg into the search a bit to see what was being constructed from the search module, it seems to be creating a proper sql query and and not returning 0 results. So something seems to be incorrect in the redirect logic.

EDIT:

Ok I have some more information. If I take a clean setup of the same site, upgrade everything along the same path then search works on that new site with different data. However if I take the code base where it is working and point it at the database of the site with the broken search then the search stops working there. So it seems to be related to the database. Also of note when I do a search it shows in the search logs, and shows that there are x results but then I get a 404 page on the front end.

Thanks,
Cory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got this working. Some how the template synch tool had created multiple versions of the same template group in the database. I usually don't check the ui for template groups but when I did it reared it's head. It was really weird because only one version of the search folder was in my codebase but three redundant versions where in the db.

Comment: This just happened to me as well with EE 2.9.2. I only had 2 search groups. Strange. Went to Template Manager and deleted the duplicate Search template group that was  in there. One had all my templates and the other only had one template in it, so that was the one that was not synced up and is the one I deleted.

Answer (score -1):

For each of the channels you're searching you need to specifically set the Search Results URL. This is in Admin > Channel Administration > Channels and under Path Settings. In your case make sure they're pointing to `/search/index`.

Comment: Thank you Ian I will give this a try. I am not sure why it would have just started to happend, wouldn't this only matter for the link generated. I am not even able to get to the search result page.

Comment: The upgrade *may* have thrown one or two things off but it's hard to be sure exactly what has changed. If you can't see the search results page (or at least a message saying no results matched) by navigating directly to that URI then it would suggest that there are other errors. In Admin > General Configuration check that your index.php pages is set along with your CP index page. I'd also check your .htaccess file if you're on Apache. Does this exist? What's in it?

Comment: Everything is correct in the general configs. I tried completely erasing the htaccess file but this did not help. :(

Comment: OK, just to address the elephant in the room, have you made sure that the Search module in Addons > Modules is installed? Is it version 2.2? Also, if you have no .htaccess file then you'll have index.php in the URL so try inserting that in the URL prior to the template_group/template. (Also try index.php?). What does all of that yield?

Comment: Search module check, search version check, attempting to hit the url's directly is also giving a 404

Comment: When you say attempting to hit the URLs directory is that both with and without index.php in the path? If you have no .htaccess file to remove them then you will need to include it.